# WSO2 AS find datasources

Tags: java, wso2, datasource, wso2-as

I have a few data sources defined from the carbon management console, where can I find those stored?

I have already looked through the files but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not stored in any file. They are stored in the registry. See this location in registry.

`/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource/`

Edit: You can browse registry like this.

[image]

Comment: and where is this _system? I tried in the wso2server/repository/components and couldn't find that org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource

Comment: Do you have any idea how is the password encrypted? I need that decrypted. Tried to search online but couldn't find anything

Comment: You are not supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you create a data source, you can find it in this registry location:

```
/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource/
```